# non-recursively replace built-in javascript functions

Tags: javascript, prompt, scoping, built-in

I am writing some bookmarklets here and I have some questions related to built-in javascript functions.

Let's say I want to replace the built-in prompt function (not necessarily in a bookmarklet).  That seems easy enough, but is there a way to call the builtin prompt function from within this replacement?

```
prompt = function(message){
    var tmp = prompt(message);
    hook(tmp);
    return tmp;
}
```

I couldn't get the scoping to work out right; this example yields infinite recursion.

Also is there a way to restore the default behavior of a builtin javascript function that has been replaced (without hanging on to an extra reference).

Comment: Indent lines by 4 spaces if you want to type code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(function () {
    var old_prompt = prompt;
    prompt = function (msg) {
        var tmp = old_prompt(msg);
        hook(tmp);
        return tmp;
    };
    prompt.restore = function () { prompt = old_prompt; }
    // analogous for other functions you want to replace
})();
```

Wrapping it up in a (self-executing) function ensures that `old_prompt` doesn't leak to the outside. You do need to expose *something* though. I chose to provide a function doing the restoring, for convenience and perhaps, one could say, future-proofing and encapsulation. As long as higher order functions refrain from fiddling with someone else's scope...

Also, no, it's (I'd assume) not possible to restore the previous value of a variable without any reference to it (the old value), even if that value happened to be a built-in. Even if it was possible, it'd be a pretty obscure trick - this way works, so let's just stick with it.

(Credit for `func.restore` goes to Martijn)

Comment: On a side note, I've seen this trick more commonly in Lua (where it's even easier thanks to the `do ... end` block - got its own scope but executes instantly and once, so it ends up being merely more than a nicer-looking self-executing function).

Comment: You could even assign the `restore_funcs` to the (new) `prompt` function, saving yet another global variable: `prompt.restore = function () { prompt = old_prompt; }`  
To restore the original prompt, just do `prompt.restore()`.

Comment: Please return `restore_funcs` instead of referencing it as a `global` variable.

Comment: @Raynos: Return to whom? And we're already manipulating global scope.

Comment: If there were some obscure way to restore it without a reference, I'd like to know.  That way, when running a bookmarklet, I can know I'm always getting the desired behavior.